# Angular Application stays in memory even after being destroyed

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, memory-leaks, ng-bootstrap

I'm developing a micro frontend with **Tailor** and **Angular 8.2.14**.
Analyzing the js heap size, with chrome dev tools, when I navigate to another page from the main application the memory is not released.

I know that ngOnDestroy is only fired when the class which it has been implemented on is destroyed within the context of a running browser session.
In other words, ngOnDestroy is not reliably called in the following scenarios:

- Page refresh
- Tab close
- Browser close
- Navigation away from page

To mitigate this problem I tried this workaround in **main.ts**:

```
let appModule: NgModuleRef<AppModule> | undefined;

platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .then((app: NgModuleRef<AppModule>) => (appModule = app))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    if (appModule) {
        const testability = appModule.injector.get(TestabilityRegistry);
        appModule.destroy();
        testability.unregisterApplication("app-root");
    }
    appModule = undefined;
})
```

Is there a way to completely destroy an Angular application?

Comment: What memory is not released? If you're looking at the browser memory, than it is the responsibility of the browser. If you're looking at the memory of your ng development server, than there is a fault in some of the dependencies or the ng server itself. Please be specific.

Comment: If I open chrome dev tools and get heap shanpshot after and before f5, I have same multiples Components and the Memory isn't released.

Comment: If the memory is not released, then that is a browser implementation detail. Perhaps it looks like the memory is not released, but actually the memory build-up is very fast and the initial memory usage of your app is just higher than you'd expect.